# What are good mitigations for balancing secure external anonymous sharing from Sharepoint/One with convenience?

Tags: dlp, microsoft-onedrive, microsoft-sharepoint-online

What are good mitigation techniques to allow corp users to share files externally with anyone, yet maintain some kind of control?

Ie. OneDrive and SharePoint can allow users to share a file with “anyone” indefinitely.
This is risky as that link can be forwarded/posted anywhere and for anyone.

On the other hand, if don’t give users that option, they’ll share it anyway using any one of a number of 3rd party services. Once do that, lose control.

Is the mitigation to have DLP policies in place, and allow for content that considered safe to be shared?

Or use a 3rd-party solution that doesn't share from native Sharepoint sites?

Comment: Once you share with anyone, you lose control, no matter what controls you have in the corporate cloud sharing service...